# Is it possible to add objective c code in ionic?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ionic-framework, push-notification

I have created the app in ionic framework and sucessfully build in ios. Is it possible to add objective c code in ionic source code or can we call those native methods from Ionic (js). Also i need to add local notification on push message. Please suggest how to make this possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is creating your own cordova plugin:

A general introduction:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/

And the guide to create iOS plugins:https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/plugin.html

Generally check for existing native plugins before trying to implement your own:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/

Comment: ok Thanks! I'll do. btw Can we try local notification( http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/localNotification/) ?
Fire the notfication from iOS objc c and receive it from js using ngcordava local notification? Will it work, did you try it before?

Comment: @Gopik: yes, you can. Check the documentation her: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications. I didn't use this plugin, but other native plugins.

Comment: Ok Thanks! I'll try